# Access denied when using Remove-Item even with -Force because file is in use

Tags: windows, powershell

I am using PowerShell to delete all files from a folder.

```
Remove-Item C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\SF\Log\Traces\* -Force
```

Problem is it throws `Access is denied` error because there is one file (the latest one generated by the process) being used by some process.

If I try to delete that particular file using `Delete` button on keyword then I get same error. But if I use `Shift + Delete` then I am able to delete file successfully.

Even if I run PowerShell as Administrator, I get same error.

How do I tell PowerShell to `Shift + Delete` file?

Comment: See https://www.leeholmes.com/moving-and-deleting-really-locked-files-in-powershell/ about using *MoveFileEx*, which will delete the locked file after reboot.

Comment: I would write that as an answer, reference, quote, etc. to preserve the link only content on SU. If leeholmes.com ever goes away, links are no good.